# Why MyApp and MaterialApp are underlined? The code is from initial flutter demo project

Tags: flutter, dart

Started my new project - got always MaterialApp underlined. Requires bottomNavigationBar. I tried it differently: started a demo project in flutter - MyApp and MaterialApp are underlined as well. So i cannot run the project.

Here is the initial code of demo project:

````
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),);
        
  }
}```

Please, tell me, what it wants? It is a code , made by flutter, i mean...

MyApp MyApp({Key? key})
package:project/main.dart

**2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.**

Thank you
````

Answer (score 0):

have you imported material app? your code should look like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: MyTheme.appTheme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes. the package is imported in the project by flutter.

Comment: found a solution for one of the problems: bottomNavigationBar: child;
get child => null;

Comment: now - MyApp:

 MyApp MyApp({Key? key})
package:project/main.dart

2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.

Which one??????